# Euler problem c++ / std::library usage

Tags: c++, c++11, project-euler

Euler problems (projecteuler.net) often invites to quick and dirty solutions.

While hurrying through [Problem 32](http://projecteuler.net/problem=32) I found myself in want of the std:: toolkit. Not sure what it is though.

The problem description is included in the first comment.

I would really appreciate any suggestions as for the usage of the tools provided by standard c++ (11 if need be, lambdas might make it more succinct/elegant).

```
/* 
 * File:   main.cpp
 * Author: cpt_giraffe
 *
 * 

 * We shall say that an n-digit number is pandigital if it makes use of all the 
 * digits 1 to n exactly once; for example, 
 * the 5-digit number, 15234, is 1 through 5 pandigital.

 * The product 7254 is unusual, as the identity, 39 × 186 = 7254, 
 * containing multiplicand, multiplier, and product is 1 through 9 pandigital.

 * Find the sum of all products whose multiplicand/multiplier/product 
 * identity can be written as a 1 through 9 pandigital.

 * HINT: Some products can be obtained in more than one way 
 * so be sure to only include it once in your sum.

 * Created on November 27, 2013, 9:41 PM
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

// store the products, a set is ideal because of the HINT:
set<unsigned> products;

/**
 * Insert to products if string arguments is a proper product
 */
void insert_if_product(string factor1, string factor2, string product) {
    stringstream values(factor1 + " " + factor2 + " " + product);

    // is this a valid product.  (Most cases says no)
    unsigned f1, f2, p;
    values >> f1 >> f2 >> p;
    if (f1 * f2 == p) {
        products.insert(p);
    }

}

/**
 * magnitudes needs to add up: I'm checking 
 * 9 digits total
 * m1 * m3 = m5
 * m1 * m4 = m4
 * m2 * m3 = m4
 * Is this all?
 * 
 * @param check this permutation
 */
void check_products(string perm) {
    // all permutations are coming from perm, so no need to perm stuff here.
    string factor1 = perm.substr(0, 1);
    string factor2 = perm.substr(1, 3);
    string product = perm.substr(4, 5);

    insert_if_product(factor1, factor2, product);

    factor1 = perm.substr(0, 1);
    factor2 = perm.substr(1, 4);
    product = perm.substr(5, 4);

    insert_if_product(factor1, factor2, product);

    factor1 = perm.substr(0, 2);
    factor2 = perm.substr(2, 3);
    product = perm.substr(5, 4);

    insert_if_product(factor1, factor2, product);

}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    string s = "123456789";
    do {
        check_products(s);

    } while (next_permutation(s.begin(), s.end()));

    // Test case
    if (products.find(7254) != products.end()) {
        cout << "found 7254" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "did not find 7254" << endl;
    }
    unsigned sum = 0;

    sum = accumulate(products.begin(), products.end(), 0);
    cout << "Sum:" << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think, you should add a reference to the original task in your comment. I think it's at least as important as the date and stating that you were the author.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Your conversions are... pretty WTF :)

   ```
   void insert_if_product(string const& factor1, string const& factor2, string const& product) {
       auto p = std::stoul(product);
       if (std::stoul(factor1, nullptr, 10) * std::stoul(factor2, nullptr, 10) == p) {
           products.insert(p);
       }
   }
   ```

   I mean why use an intermediate stream? Why, if you're using a stream, build it using string *concatenation*? Also, why pass in copies of read-only strings?!
2. avoid unnecesary allocations:

   ```
   string factor1 = perm.substr(0, 1);
   string factor2 = perm.substr(1, 3);
   string product = perm.substr(4, 5);
   ```

   is gonna do a lot of allocations. Probably more than you'd think. At least, reuse `factor1`,`factor2` and `product` capacities? (My sample below makes them static)

   > #### ***Edit** Squeezing a few more drops out:*
3. avoiding strings in more places avoids the temps from `perm.substr()`. Now I just directly assign by indices:

   ```
       factor1.assign(perm.begin()+0, perm.begin()+1);
       factor2.assign(perm.begin()+1, perm.begin()+4);
       product.assign(perm.begin()+4, perm.begin()+9);
   ```
4. using `unordered_set` seems to shave off milliseconds on average :)

Quick performance comparison (g++ -std=c++11 -march=native -O3`) shows the time taken goes down from ~1.036s to ~0.116s.

So, roughly **8.9x speed** effectively.

Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <sstream>

// store the products, a set is ideal because of the HINT:
std::unordered_set<unsigned> products;

/**
 * Insert to products if string arguments is a proper product
 */
void insert_if_product(std::string const& factor1, std::string const& factor2, std::string const& product) {
    auto p = std::stoul(product);
    if (std::stoul(factor1, nullptr, 10) * std::stoul(factor2, nullptr, 10) == p) {
        products.insert(p);
    }
}

/**
 * magnitudes needs to add up: I'm checking 
 * 9 digits total
 * m1 * m3 = m5
 * m1 * m4 = m4
 * m2 * m3 = m4
 * Is this all?
 * 
 * @param check this permutation
 */

void check_products(std::string const& perm)
{
    static std::string factor1, factor2, product;
    // all permutations are coming from perm, so no need to perm stuff here.
    factor1.assign(perm.begin()+0, perm.begin()+1);
    factor2.assign(perm.begin()+1, perm.begin()+4);
    product.assign(perm.begin()+4, perm.begin()+9);

    insert_if_product(factor1, factor2, product);

//  factor1.assign(perm.begin()+0, perm.begin()+1);
    factor2.assign(perm.begin()+1, perm.begin()+5);
    product.assign(perm.begin()+5, perm.begin()+9);

    insert_if_product(factor1, factor2, product);

    factor1.assign(perm.begin()+0, perm.begin()+2);
    factor2.assign(perm.begin()+2, perm.begin()+5);
//  product.assign(perm.begin()+5, perm.begin()+9);

    insert_if_product(factor1, factor2, product);
}

int main() {
    std::string s = "123456789";

    do {
        check_products(s);
    } while(std::next_permutation(std::begin(s), std::end(s)));

    std::cout << "Sum:" << std::accumulate(products.begin(), products.end(), 0u) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: **updated** now 8x faster, `check_products` back as a free function (better IMO). Also, note subtle things like `0u` in the `accumulate` call!

Comment: And thank you for your time and insights sehe.

Comment: Oh hey, shaved off another 15% after _actually looking at the indices :)_. Now ~8.9x faster :)